# Includes in Eclipse Mars C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-mars

I have defined the function `int getRandomNumber()` in my `Main.cpp` file. Outside if this file, there are classes, made up of header files and class files.

The function `int getRandomNumber()` cannot be accessed from inside other class files for some reason, even though it is supposedly global.

The code in the `Main.cpp` looks something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getRandomNumber() {
    return 4; // Chosen by fair dice roll
}

#include "folder/ClassName.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ClassName t;
    t.test();
    return 0;
}
```

The inside of `ClassName.h` looks something like this:

```
#ifndef SRC_CLASSNAME_H_
#define SRC_CLASSNAME_H_

class ClassName {
public:
    ClassName();
    virtual ~ClassName();
    void test();
};

#endif /* SRC_CLASSNAME_H_ */
```

Lastly, the insides of `ClassName.cpp` hold the contents of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ClassName.h"

using namespace std;

ClassName::ClassName() {
    cout << "Created" << endl;
}
ClassName::~ClassName() {
    cout << "Destroyed" << endl;
}
void ClassName::test() {
    cout << "Tested" << endl;
}
```

How comes that "Created", "Tested" and "Destroyed" are all printed to the console, even though the `ClassName.cpp` file is never explicitly included anywhere?

Why can `int getRandomNumber()` not be accessed from the `ClassName.h` file, even though the preprocessor pastes it in where it is included? The same thing applies to `<iostream>`. Why does it need to be included again in the `.cpp` file?

Comment: It seems that the `ClassName.cpp` file is in the project, and so it built with the rest of the program. And you can't access `getRandomNumber` from the header file (or any other source file) because it's not *declared* anywhere else.

Comment: You need to move the `getRandomNumber()` to a header, then include that header in `ClassName.h` in order for you to use it but still retaining the function in the `Main.cpp` file. And I think you're confusing headers with source files (c, cpp), the compiler treats each source file as an individual therefore you need to include `iostream` in both cpp files.

Comment: Oh, I understand this concept now. Thank you both! So in header files, you _declare_ things and then in the `.cpp` files you put the content in, that can be accessed from any other source file that has just the header included.
What should I do with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access `getRandomNumber()` from multiple locations you can move it to a header, which you then include in all source files that need the function:

**MyHeader.h**

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

int getRandomNumber();

// ... other stuff here

#endif /* MYHEADER_H */
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "MyHeader.h"

int getRandomNumber() {
    return 4; // Chosen by fair dice roll
}

// ... other stuff here
```

Now you can access `getRandomNumber()` by `#include`-ing it in any source file.